# iOS can not get image from json to TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, imageurl

I want to get image url from json in internet link and show it on the TableViewCell, but only load successfully only text on 2 label.

Here is my code:

**MoviesCellController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class MoviesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var movies: [NSDictionary]!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://coderschool-movies.herokuapp.com/movies?api_key=xja087zcvxljadsflh214")!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request,
            queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in

                let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let json = json {
                    self.movies = json!["movies"] as? [NSDictionary]
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let movies = movies {
            return movies.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MovieCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MovieCell

        let movie = movies![indexPath.row]

        cell.titleLabel.text = movie["title"] as? String
        cell.synopsisLabel.text = movie["synopsis"] as? String

        let url = NSURL(string: movie.valueForKeyPath("posters.thumbnail") as! String)!
        cell.posterView.setImageWithURL(url)

        return cell
    }

}
```

**MovieCell.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class MovieCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var synopsisLabel: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet var posterView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

My MainStoryBoard

[image]

When I run the simulator it only show like this, doesn't show the image anywhere.

my Info.plist file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should try with `setImageWithURLRequest`.

Comment: I don't know how to send parameter on it.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569971/afnetworkings-setimagewithurlrequest-sets-image-in-wrong-cell-after-scroll-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your Info.plist file.

[image]

Check this post for more detail: [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: Maybe I have not added it yet, I check this link but where should I add it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file

Comment: Info.plist file, you can search in your project if you're new with Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.

Assuming that the library you are using to "setImageWithURL" is working, I would check that the posterView outlet is properly wired up, and that url is actually being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

### use PINRemoteImage pods.just import it and write the below code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

custumcell.profilePic?.pin_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: profileImageUrl!), placeholderImage: UIImage(), processorKey: "Ball", processor:
                        { (result, cost) -> UIImage! in
                        return result.image
                        }, completion: { (result) -> Void in })